# charset utf-8 in asp.net for special turkish characters

Tags: asp.net, razor, utf-8, character-encoding

I put `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the head, and DOCTYPE at the top of my `_Layout.cshtml`, but still when I'm viewing the website, the special Turkish characters are displayed as like &#23'1; and such in the **source**, not in the page. The webpage displays them correctly, the source file has the problem.. 
Do you know what else I should do to correct this?

Answer (score 10):

I had exactly the same problem, tried all the solutions and none of them worked, checked .cshtml file encoding with Notepad++ and it was correct (utf8 with BOM), SaveAs file with encoding (as shown above) but the problem still persisted.

Finally I found out that there was nothing wrong with my razor files, it seems that ASP.Net core MVC does not set UTF-8 encoding as default encoding and it must be set if needed by developer.

I added the below code at the end of `ConfigureServices` method of `Program.cs` (it adds UTF-8 encoding to default encodings)  and the problem solved.

```
services.AddWebEncoders(o => {
            o.TextEncoderSettings = new System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
        });
```

Comment: my files are UTF-8, no BOM, and this solution still works. Thanks

Comment: @JohannMedina happy coding :)

Answer (score 9):

Try to save your source file as UTF-8 **with** BOM.
I was having a similar issue and it seems that Razor expects files to have the BOM signature.

In Visual Studio: FILE > Advanced Save Options:

[image: Advanced Save Options dialog]